# node js slicing buffer modifies data

Tags: node.js

I have the following node js code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const SEND_SIZE = 256;
var fs = require('fs');

function append(data){
  "use strict";
  fs.appendFile("./testcopy.bin", data, function(errorwrite){
    if (errorwrite) {
      throw errorwrite;
    }
  });
}

fs.readFile("./test.bin", function(error, data){
  "use strict";
  if(error)
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else
  {
    for(var start=0, len=data.length; start < len; start+=SEND_SIZE)
    {
      var d = data.slice(start, start+SEND_SIZE);
      append(d);
    }
  }
});
```

When I call it like this `node ./main.js`, and I compare `test.bin` with `testcopy.bin` using `vim -d test.bin testcopy.bin`, I see that the files are not identical. The file `test.bin` is a binary file. Can you help me to explain why? I just want to slice the contents of the buffer without modifying it. When using regular text files, the problem does not occur.

Eventually, I would also like to pad the last slice with zero's so that the last slice also has a length of `SEND_SIZE`. Can you help me with that?